# How to make the method recognize that the text argument passed is file name?

Tags: java, file-io, html-parsing, awt

I created two classes,"HtmlParser" for parsing html tags and "ConvertToText" class to accept the source html file name.HtmlParser class has a method called htmlTextParser(Filename).I wrote

HtmlParser.htmlTextParser(textfieldname.getText());

statement to call HtmlParser class from ConvertToText class, so that when I enter a html file name in textfield, it needs to be passed to htmlTextParser() method. The problem here is, the text must be accepted as filename.

The error I got was htmlTextParser(String) is undefined for the class HtmlParser.Please help

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes,

`new File(name).isFile()` will return true if `name` exists and is a file(eg. not a directory)

Comment: I tried this too but it displays an error that htmlTextParser(boolean) is undefined for the HtmlParser class

Comment: I think, you have misunderstood this solution. Only run htmlTextParser(String name), if the above expression returns true. For this you have to use `if`, eg. `if(new File(name).isFile()){ HtmlParser.htmlTextParser(textfieldname.getText());}`
Of course, you can't pass a boolean to a function which expects a string.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. This is a compile-time error. How can a run-time solution possibly solve that?

Comment: Thanks all.I did as David Frank explained and it finally worked.

Answer (score 3):

> htmlTextParser(String) is undefined for the class HtmlParser

So it doesn't exist. So you haven't written it. So write it. But I suggest that you make it a File parameter, not a String parameter, so you won't get confused like this.